# Manual build of State machine

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I have a statemachine using Spring, this is constructed using annotations

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachine
class StateMachineConfiguration extends
    StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<State, Event> {
```

(For the states/transitions)

and a number of handler classes for the actions

```
@WithStateMachine
public class AwaitingData {

@OnStateEntry(target = "AwaitingData")
public void onEntry() {
```

I want to build this statemachine manually so I can test various aspects.  I do not want to duplicate the configuration for the test, I want to use the "real" config.
I can easily build the machine using the StateMachineBuilder and my configuration class

```
private StateMachine<State, Event> buildStateMachine() {
    StateMachineConfiguration config = new StateMachineConfiguration();
    StateMachineBuilder.Builder<State, Event> builder = StateMachineBuilder.builder();
    config.configure(builder.configureStates());
    config.configure(builder.configureTransitions());
    return builder.build();
}
```

but... How do I now add the actions?
I want to add specific actions (depending on the specific test) with mocks, etc.

I have stepped through the library as it configures the machine but I still can't see where/how the annotated functions are added.
Google is little help, usually sending me straight to the Spring docs which don't seem to cover my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [gh462](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/462) to polish docs.

Essentially as `@WithStateMachine` is a spring application context integration, you need to make machine aware of a `BeanFactory`. Manual builder were added so that people can use machine outside of a normal spring app context and bean model. Before I get docs polished, see from [MethodAnnotationWithBuilderTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/master/spring-statemachine-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/statemachine/annotation/MethodAnnotationWithBuilderTests.java) how this can be done.